# Listing subfolders in an Assets fieldtype

Tags: matrix, assets

I have a Assets fieldtype within a Matrix fieldtype column.

Is it possible to list subfolders for the uploads dir?

ATM, I only get top level folders as per the attached screenshot.

Im my Images folder, I have News and Product subfolders...I'd like these listed if possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know that's not possible. If you have a folder you need to use like that you'll have to just create a new root folder for it (if you don't want to use one of the existing ones)